# Como filtrar time em um campo datime no eloquent?

Tags: php, datetime, laravel-eloquent, data, laravel-5.1

Como consigo comparar se um horário é igual a um horário armazenado em uma coluna `datetime` usando o Eloquent?

Comment: Como você está armazenando a data no banco?

Comment: nesse formato (2018-01-01 14:50:35)

Comment: Você quer que a consulta seja por data e hora ou só por hora?

Comment: consultar apenas pela hora

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considerando que você quer desconsiderar a data, mas considerar apenas o horário, você precisa usar a função `TIME` do Mysql para formatar a coluna com formato `datetime` para formato de tempo. Assim sendo, é necessário usar o método `DB::raw()` do Laravel, para ele aceitar uma expressão Mysql no `WHERE`.

Exemplo:

```
 // Pega todos os usuários que foram cadastrados às 23:59:01

 Usuario::where(DB::raw('TIME(created_at)'), '=', '23:59:01')->get();
```

Se você quiser ignorar os segundos, provavelmente terá que fazer um `whereBetween`, e especificar os segundos `00` e `59`. Assim:

```
 // Retorna os usuários que foram cadastrados às 13:38, independente dos segundos 

 Usuario::whereBetween(DB::raw('TIME(created_at)'), ['13:38:00', '13:38:59'])->get();
```

Se precisar dessas horario dinamicamente, pode usar a função `date` com o parâmetro `H:i:s`.

```
  Usuario::where(DB::raw('TIME(created_at)'), '=', date('H:i:s'))->get()
```

Além do mais, é perfeitamente possível definir a data atual, ignorando os segundos, para o caso do `whereBetween`

```
Usuario::whereBetween(DB::raw('TIME(created_at)'), [date('H:i:00'), date('H:i:59')])->get();
```

## Atualização

A função `HOUR` que eu havia colocando anteriormente estava errada. `HOUR` retorna o valor inteiro da hora de uma data.

Por exemplo:

```
 2015-01-01 23:40:30
```

Retonaria:

```
 23
```

Já a função `TIME` retorna `23:40:30`, como String.

Comment: Quem deu o negativo poderia explicar? Porque eu fiz a resposta exatamente como o AP pediu.

Comment: Veja não fui eu que deu o negativo, mas, a sua resposta está errada ou o usuário perguntou errado, porque? `hour` pega somente a hora e o que pude perceber na pergunta dele é horas, minutos e segundos de um `datetime`? veja a pergunta é muito confusa e até as suas respostas estão erradas, porque você pega exemplo 19 horas e compara com um hora completa também tem problemas

Comment: Foi exatamente o que ele falou pra eu fazer nos comentários. Dá uma olhada ali.

Comment: Mesmo assim as suas comparações estão erradas, é isso que eu estou querendo dizer!

Comment: Como erradas? Você testou? Eu testei aqui e deu certo. Ele pediu pra pegar "o horário que foram armazenadas". Se foi armazenada as `13:10:01` de uma data qualquer, a consulta funciona corretamente. Agora, se o usuário necessitar de outra coisa, ele é que precisa especificar na pergunta (e isso não seria motivo válido pra negativo).

Comment: Caro Wallace `Usuario::where(DB::raw('HOUR(created_at)'), '=', '23:59:01')->get();` você que precisa testar porque `23 != '23:59:01'`  ou estou enganado?

Comment: Eu acho que não entendi o `23` aí. O usuário pediu pra pesquisar pelo horário, e não pela "hora".

Comment: @VirgilioNovic ahhhhhhhhhhhhhh, sim. Você tem razão. Eu coloquei a função errada. O certo é `TIME`

Comment: se o usuário pediu para verificar pela hora blz, então deveria ser `Usuario::where(DB::raw('HOUR(created_at)'), '=', '23')` ??? ou não. porque Hour retorna somente o valor da hora

Comment: @VirgilioNovic valeu por assinalar. Realmente... O `HOUR` retorna a hora, o `TIME` retorna `23:59:01`.

Comment: talvez agora a pessoa que viu o seu problema coloque o up para você! era bom ele ter dito... neh mas, não é assim que funciona para alguns usuários

Comment: @VirgilioNovic não estou muito certo, kkk. Se quem negativou antes tivesse assinalado isso, já teria feito a edição. Mas muito obrigado, cara.  Eu tinha testado com `TIME` e coloquei `HOUR` na resposta, uma grande navalhada, kkkkk